# MinGW - SEH и SJLJ. Странное поведение

Tags: c++, исключения

Имеется в наличии невероятно простой код:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class C {
    public :
        C() try {
            throw std::runtime_error("C::C");
        } 
        catch (...) { }
};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

Компилируем этот код компилятором MinGW-builds 8.1.0 x86_64 **SJLJ** и, запустив полученное приложение, получаем следующий вывод:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  C::C

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

А теперь сделаем то же самое, заменив компилятор на MinGW-builds 8.1.0 x86_64 **SEH**. С удивлением наблюдаем, что строка с сообщением о типе исключения исчезла:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Собственно, вопрос. Почему? Что происходит? Так и должно быть или я чего-то не понимаю?

P.S. Интересно, что если у конструктора убрать *function-try-block*, т.е. привести его к виду

```
C() {
    throw std::runtime_error("C::C");
}
```

то вывод при обоих способах обработки исключений идентичный.

---

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Если добавить конструктору спецификатор `noexcept`, то поведение вновь становится одинаковым:

```
C() noexcept try {
    throw std::runtime_error("C::C");
}
catch (...) { }
```

Comment: В одном случаи вы кидаете исключение в конструкторе, а в обработчике ничего не делаете, а в другом  вы оставляете право обработать исключение, вызывающей функции( в данном случаи  main() ) , но она  вообше не обрабатывет исключение, что то же самое. Конечно так и должно быть

Comment: @ARHovsepyan После блока `catch` компилятор вставляет неявный `throw` возникшего исключения, так что оно не обрабатывается и уходит дальше. Кроме того, это не объясняет разного поведения для SEH и SJLJ.

Comment: Немного изменил вопрос для лучшего понимания.

Comment: Компилятор GCC на coliru выводит `what()` независимо от того, есть ли в конструкторе function-try-block. Поведение terminate handler по умолчанию - зависит от реализации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формально говоря, у вас в коде нет "обработки" исключений. Исключение, пойманное function-try-block конструктора, невозможно "подавить" - оно все равно будет перевыброшено автоматически, если вы этого не сделаете сами. То есть в любом из ваших вариантов исключение остается необработанным.

Если исключение не обработано, то вызывается `std::terminate`, которая вызовет текущий обработчик terminate (terminate handler). А что делает установленный по умолчанию обработчик terminate - определяется реализацией. Вот эти различия между реализациями вы и наблюдаете.

Например, если в GCC при помощи `std::set_terminate` задать свой пустой обработчик terminate, то вывод о типе исключения и вывод `what()` исчезнет.

Comment: Но обработчик-то, что логично предположить, один. Почему же у него разное поведение для SEH в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия `try`? Насколько я понимаю, исключение в обработчик придёт одинаковое в обоих случаях.

Comment: @user303900: Почему один? Я бы предположил, что обработчики разные.

Comment: Хм... С моей точки зрения это немного нелогично, но может быть Вы и правы...

Comment: Дополнил вопрос одним интересным моментом. Похоже, что обработчик действительно разный и выбирается в зависимости от того, может ли конструктор выбрасывать исключения. Видимо, при наличии function-try-block компилятор ставит один обработчик, а при его отсутствии или же при наличии спецификатора `noexcept` ставит другой, предполагая что если есть `try`, то исключение может быть обработано и выведено сообщение пользователю, а если нет, то надо вывести его из обработчика. Странно что такое поведение присутствует только в SEH, но оставим это на совести разработчиков MinGW.